# Mocking a controller that do PUT function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Mock of my controller to update data inside user. From the code I am trying to update only the email, password, and age. Is this how we should do the mock? Because I'm still really new with this Mockito and Junit

> Controller Mock

```
@Test
public void testUpdateUserController() throws Exception{
    String username = "User";
    String email = "user@email.com";
    String password = "password123";
    int age = 90;
 Mockito.when(userService.updateUser(username,email,password,age)).then(invocationOnMock -> {
     User user = new User();
     user.setUsername("User");
     user.setEmail("user@user.com");
     user.setPassword("123456");
     user.setAge(12);
     user.setAddress("11111");
     user.setIsActive(true);
     return Optional.of(user);
 });
 mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put(BASE_URL + "/users/{username}",username)
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
 Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).updateUser(userCaptor.capture(),emailCaptor.capture(),passwordCaptor.capture(),ageCaptor.capture());
    Assert.assertEquals("User", userCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("user@email.com", emailCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("password123", passwordCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("90", ageCaptor.getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("11111", addressCaptor.getValue());
}
```

> UserServiceImpl

```
@Override
public boolean updateUser(String username, String email, String password, Integer age) {
    Optional<User> userList = userRepository.findByUsernameAndIsActiveTrue(username);
    if (userList.isPresent()) {
        User user = userList.get();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setAge(age);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my code samples for MVC Mocks

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TrainingControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private TrainingService trainingService;

    @Mock
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    @InjectMocks
    private TrainingController controller = new TrainingController();


    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionController())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateHappyPath() throws Exception {
        Training training = new Training();
        Optional<Training> result = Optional.of(training);
        TrainingExt ext = result
                .map(TrainingExt::of)
                .get();

        when(trainingService.createTraining(any(Training.class))).thenReturn(result);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String trainingPayloadJSON = mapper.writerFor(Training.class).writeValueAsString(training);
        String trainingExtJSON = mapper.writerFor(TrainingExt.class).writeValueAsString(ext);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(TestConstants.POST_TRAINING_URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(trainingPayloadJSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(content().json(trainingExtJSON));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPutHappyPath() throws Exception {
        Training training = new Training();
        Optional<Training> result = Optional.of(training);
        TrainingExt ext = result
                .map(TrainingExt::of)
                .get();

        when(trainingService.update(any(Training.class))).thenReturn(result);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String trainingPayloadJSON = mapper.writerFor(Training.class).writeValueAsString(training);
        String trainingExtJSON = mapper.writerFor(TrainingExt.class).writeValueAsString(ext);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put(TestConstants.GET_PUT_DELETE_TRAINING_URI, TestConstants.ID)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(trainingPayloadJSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(content().json(trainingExtJSON));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddAttendeesHappyPath() throws Exception {
        Attendees attendees = new Attendees();
        Optional<Training> result = Optional.of(new Training());
        TrainingExt ext = result
                .map(TrainingExt::of)
                .get();

        when(trainingService.registerTrainingAttendees(any(Attendees.class))).thenReturn(result);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String attendeesPayloadJSON = mapper.writerFor(Attendees.class).writeValueAsString(attendees);
        String trainingExtJSON = mapper.writerFor(TrainingExt.class).writeValueAsString(ext);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(TestConstants.ADD_ATTENDEES_URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(attendeesPayloadJSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(content().json(trainingExtJSON));
    }
}
```